# jquery ui updates through code do not fire while submitting form

Tags: jquery, forms, html, submit, loading

I have a loading div that shows in between different calls to the server.
Here is the code:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
        $("#loadingDiv").show();
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("form:first").submit();                        
    });
```

It all works well if I comment out the third line of code to submit the form. But when I put the code to submit the form next to these ui update calls, none of them take effect, and the browser wait cursor shows till the result of the form submit are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `preventDefault()` to prevent the default submit from occurring. As you have it, the form is being submitted before any of the click handler code can run.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (e) { // note event object passed in
    e.preventDefault(); // add this
    $("#loadingDiv").show();
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("form:first").submit();                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you submit a form the page will be reloaded or redirected to another place, I guess you want to use AJAX, if thats the case you might want to take a look at `ajax()` or `post()` methods and use them instead of submitting the form.

Comment: But when I do an ajax post, I will have to get the results of the post through code and process it. That will take away the automatic display of server side errors when the page reloads.. does that make sense.

Comment: Just to be clear, I do want the page to reload or get redirected. It's just that the screen changes that needs to be happen before I submit, that is not working

Comment: so you want to show the loading animation for a few seconds, then submit the form and reload the whole page?

Comment: Hi Soheil, the behavior I wanted was to let the loading animation play while the server takes its time in sending the response. Mathletics solution worked for me. But thanks for your time in helping out.